# Development vs. Production Media Location in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on user-uploaded files with Django. I often this this in various articles:

```
    urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
      url(r'^file/', include('file_app.urls')),
    ]

    if settings.DEBUG:
      urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Which implies that if DEBUG is on and you're developing, then add the MEDIA_URL path to urlpatterns so it's accessible.

So what is the appropriate way to store files in a production environment and why isn't this method suitable in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files could be stored anywhere. You will just need to update the path in your settings.py

Django does not take the responsibility to serve static or media files.
That is the job of the server that you use in production

I usually use NGINX + Gunicorn configuration. many people also use Apache.

In the end, you need to configure your server to serve the static/media files. Django will not do it.

Comment: Think I just confused myself because my current use case just involves accepting user-uploaded files and storing them somewhere. Then later referencing them to do some analysis, I'm never really serving them again.

The MEDIA_ROOT can be anything I want I not suppose

Here's basically what I was getting at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080194/where-to-store-user-uploaded-files-in-django